What sets the property ro.hardware?
I would like to know what sets the ro.hardware property. I cant seem to find in the build property files on the device. Is it set in the BoardConfig.mk or device.mk file when building android

Is this answer on Stack Overflow related? android boot - where is the init.%hardware%.rc read in init.c ? where are services started?

Also found a Google Group thread that explained how ro.hardware is set: About androidboot.hardware (note that I don't have any knowledge on this, so I won't be able to comment or answer any questions)

yes your links were helpful

Nice to hear that. Feel free to post a self-answer if possible :)
